Android Studio: Where is the Linux deployment dropdown? "No Connected Devices Found."
From within Android Studio, Flutter doctor reports that the Linux and Chrome device are available

but the Linux target deployment device isn't device isn't available to select where is usually is:

And run reports "No Connected Devices Found".
Device Explorer, Running Device and Device Manager show no Linux device.
I've found many solution to "No Connected Devices Found". None explain why the deployment target dropdown is missing and how to choose a Linux target.
How do I view the deployment devices.

That screenshot looks like the "modern UI" by Jet brains. I don't use it, so may be there is also a deployment target drop-down, but the old/classic UI definitely has it. You can switch back by disabling modern UI in settings.

Maybe. It would be nice if I could go to "Find Action" to show it. There is are no matched for *deployment*.

In my taskbar what you call "deployment target drop-down" is named Select Device (Alt+Shift+F11). With that name it is also available in the "Find Action" menu (press shift twice).
